# How to create Ajax link in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in asp.net MVC and in app I need call action and update container div via ajax, How can I do it?

```
<div id="updateContainer">
</div>

@foreach(string str in new[] {"All", "Joe", "Jane", "Bob"}){
  <div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink(str,"ApprointmentData", new {id= str })
  </div>
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should to use ajax options

```
@foreach(string str in new[] {"All", "Joe", "Jane", "Bob"}){
  <div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink(str,"ApprointmentData", new {id= str },
      new AjaxOptions{ 
            UpdateTargetId="updateContainer",
      }
    )
  </div>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link Text", "MyAction", "MyController", new { month = "January"},new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetID="YourUID here"}
```